# Proper Method to Seed Numpy and Multiple Scipy Distributions Concurrently

Tags: python, numpy, random, scipy, random-seed

Currently, I am programming a large simulation that uses random variates from multiple distributions that come from both `numpy` and `scipy.stats`, and where the distributions should also be independent. Seeking a way to ensure reproducibility, I luckily stumbled upon Abhinav's response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016959/scipy-stats-seed), where they provide an amazing example. Nevertheless, it notably only seeds a single distribution from `scipy`, whereas my code has multiple `scipy` distributions. Is there a way to seed all `scipy` distributions at once (while still seeding the `numpy` distributions)? If not all at once, is it possible to seed all of the continuous distributions? (It just seems inefficient to seed every single distribution separately). Thank you very much!

Edit: A minimal reproducible example can be found below (it is similar to Abhinav's example):

```py
from numpy.random import Generator, PCG64
from scipy.stats import binom, norm

n, p, size, seed = 10, 0.5, 10, 12345

numpy_randomGen = Generator(PCG64(seed))
scipy_randomGen = binom
scipy_randomGen2 = norm

numpy_randomGen = Generator(PCG64(seed))

# this is the part I want to simplify, as I have many distributions from scipy
# maybe there is a convention that simplifies it?
scipy_randomGen.random_state=numpy_randomGen
scipy_randomGen2.random_state=numpy_randomGen


print(scipy_randomGen.rvs(n, p, size=size))
print(scipy_randomGen2.rvs(size=size))
print(numpy_randomGen.binomial(n, p, size))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you're after. You still need to seed each distribution separately. So there's unlikely to be anything simpler then providing a random_state arg to each rvs call  as in

.rvs(n, p, size=size, random_state=...)

Here the random_state argument can be a Generator or an integer seed (however in the latter case it's constructing an old-style RandomState object and seeds it under the hood.

Comment: I was exactly asking if I need to seed each ``scipy.stats`` distribution separately, especially when seeding ``numpy`` and ``scipy.stats`` distributions! That's great to know! Thank you!

Comment: Well, you either seed each of them independently, or you rely on an implicit seeding via `np.random.seed`. The latter is discouraged.